# Proof of Egoroves Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Almost all books and articles on measure theory give proof of [Egorove's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem) by considering a sequence of double-indexed measurable sets (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem), for example). I don't find any natural way to consider these double indexed sets, and couldn't present well to the students.

I tried to follow the proof for the sequence $\{x^n\colon 0\leq x\leq 1\}$, but every time, I puzzled with question- why I am considering these kinds of double indexed sets? Can anybody give me some suggestions to present the proof of Egorove's theorem in a nice elementary, elegant form?

Comment: I worried about the original proof of Egorove. If he has proved this theorem in the way that appears in almost all books, what thoughts he put on while considering such double indexed sets? or with what ideas, he came to the end of the proof?